# Compare excel worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, vlookup, comparison

Here is the problem I have been trying to resolve all morning - I have two Excel worksheet files:

1. Subset: This file has a subset of employees with various details including training status such as in-progress, completed, etc.
2. Full-Pop: This file has a complete list of employees with the same set of information. However, the training status in this file is more updated, so for example, an employee with a training status in-progress in the 'Subset' file may have a training status of 'completed' in the 'Full-Pop'. Additionally, the Full-Pop file also has newly hired employees.

I would like to be able to compare the two files and highlight differences in Purple. Differences must include any new employees and updated values such as status or dates on Full-Pop file.

I have looked at some of the forums online, but they seem to work only for row by row comparison. Is VlookUp the solution?

I am not sure how to use it for this purpose.
Any suggestions?

I attached a [Dataset Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvuCY.jpg) attached for reference.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would you mind expanding your 'Dataset Example', by showing how the same group of example employees' data may be different in the two datasets, and how you'd like to have them visually look in the subset worksheet? (e.g. is the whole row to be highlighted, or just certain cells within each row?) You can manually apply the formatting to these few rows of data to demonstrate what you'd like Excel to do for you.

Comment: Also, is this in two sheets within a single workbook, or is this in two separate files?

Comment: Also it would be nice to see information about what you've tried, and what wasn't right about it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, VLOOKUP will find the updates. COUNTIF will find the new employees.

The image shows a simplified example that compares Sheet1 to Sheet2.

- The conditional formatting of column A is `=AND(A1<>"", COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:A, A1)=0)`. The last part means, "Is a count in Sheet2, column A, of values like cell A1 equal to zero?" If zero, that's a new employee.
- The conditional formatting of column B is `=AND(B1<>"", B1<>VLOOKUP(A1, Sheet2!A:B, 2, FALSE))`. The last part means, "Is the value in cell B1 different than the value looked up by finding a match to A1 in Sheet2, column A, and returning the value in the second column, for exact matches only?" If different, that's an update.

The first part, up to `<>""`, means "ignore blanks." The first part isn't essential, but it lets you apply the conditional formatting to an entire column and not see highlighted cells in the blank rows below your data.

[image]